# Problem upgrading 11.10 Server to 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, server, upgrade, lts

I'm experiencing some problems with upgrading Ubuntu 11.10 Server to 12.04 LTS
I have changed the `release-upgrades` files to `prompt=lts` but the `do-release-upgrade -d` doesn't work.

How can I fix that? I'm really interested to do this upgrade.

**Additional information**

```
lsb-release file
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=natty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.04"
```

**Uname -a**

```
Linux V-5477 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5.028stab091.1 #1 SMP Wed Jun 1 13:20:25 MSD 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: you sure about the information you have provided ?

Comment: try without the -d and report what happens!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `prompt=lts` a wrong option?

> If and only if upgrading from an LTS release, then edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt=lts

Source: [PreciseUpgrades - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades)